# Scrape drop down menu

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the size menu of this page.
https://www.hayabusafightwear.co.uk/hayabusa-lightweight-jiu-jitsu-gi-blue
If I copy the html and use beautiful soup it works but doesn't seem to work on the live version.
I think it is because the html is dynamic?

What is the best way to go forward? Is it even worth trying?

Thank you very much for your help.

url="https://www.hayabusafightwear.co.uk/hayabusa-lightweight-jiu-jitsu-gi-blue"

page_html = get_page_html(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

attrs = soup.find("select", {"class":"required-entry super-attribute-select"}).find_all("option")

print(attrs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the combination of selenium and bs4 to get it done:

```py
import time
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)


url = 'https://www.hayabusafightwear.co.uk/hayabusa-lightweight-jiu-jitsu-gi-blue'
data = driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
pg_html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_html, 'html.parser')

selection = soup.find("select", attrs = {"class":"required-entry super-attribute-select"})
sizes = selection.find_all('option')
for size in sizes:
    print(size.text)
'''
    R e s u l t :
Choose an Option...
A1
A4
'''
```

You can find more about it here: https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25
Regards...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I replaced 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options) by 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options = options) 
as I was getting chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH
Not sure whether it is the best way but it works.